# Spotlight on Sonoma gets out of focus

Tags: macos, spotlight, sonoma

I mostly start my apps via Spotlight. Since the Sonoma update Spotlight seems to be started out of focus and the enter button sometimes has no effect.

So what I do is hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and enter my search. If I am quick and the search results don't show, but auto-completion shows the correct app, I can just hit enter and everything is fine. But if I wait too long and the results show up the first search result is highlighted in grey. I have to press <kbd>↓</kbd> to make the highlighted app/search result blue and then press <kbd>↑</kbd> to get to the first result before I can hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to start it.

Sometimes, if the search results just popped up I can still start the app by hitting enter, but not, if I wait too long. So it seems Spotlight is "half" out of focus. Is anyone else experiencing this?